# Why some keys doesnt work on my Ubuntu laptop?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

I'm using a Lenovo Legion S7 15ACH6 laptop with Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and I've run into an unusual issue. The 'Backspace', '[' and ']' keys only work if I press another key along with it. For example, to delete a character I need to press 'Shift' + 'Backspace' for example. Strangely if I press 'Alt' + 'Backspace' or just the 'Backspace' itself, nothing happens, as if the key is broken. Likewise with the other two keys. I tried to boot into Ubuntu from a USB flash drive, the problem remains. When booting from a USB flash drive with Windows, it offers to restore the OS settings, so i didnt meet any input field to test it out. If I connect any external keyboard, everything works correctly. Updated the Linux kernel, did not help. Please tell me, can this problem be due to physical damage or is it still at the software level? What other ways are there to test it besides a complete system reinstall? May it be because of some BIOS issues?

Changing keyboard layout doesnt affect the problem

tried to press keys with `xev | grep keycode`
had the same behavior: pressing one button doesnt count in utility
with two keys pressed (with any key, even 'F1' or 'Super'):

```
0x10, keycode 50 (keysym 0xffe1, Shift_L), same_screen YES, state  
0x11, keycode 22 (keysym 0xff08, BackSpace), same_screen YES
```

Comment: If an external keyboard works correctly, then suspect a hardware issue with your keyboard. Perhaps run `xev | grep keycode` and report back what is given in the terminal when you press Backspace, Shift, Shift+Backspace and Alt+Backspace

Comment: followed your advice and got the same result. With one button pressing doesnt count in this utility, but if I press two keys, then it displays it correctly

Comment: like this:
state 0x10, keycode 50 (keysym 0xffe1, Shift_L), same_screen YES,
state 0x11, keycode 22 (keysym 0xff08, BackSpace), same_screen YES,

Comment: Add information relevant to the problem to the question: use "edit".

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I've managed to solve the problem in the following way:

- boot up with Windows installing usb
- open terminal (shift + f10)
- start typing - at first nothing happened; then the keys started to work properly
- reboot back to ubuntu
- now everything is fine - all keys work properly